# Data privacy in hyperledger sawtooth?

Tags: intel, hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger, hyperledger-sawtooth

Is there any way to maintain data privacy in hyperledger sawtooth,as we cannot create channels like hyperledger fabric?

Comment: Clarify if you mean just data (in flight, at rest) or data and the fact that two parties may have an exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In sawtooth, transactions can usually be seen by all participants. But there is a transaction family that enables chanel-like behavior (as seen in fabric). See here:

https://sawtooth.hyperledger.org/docs/core/releases/0.8.8/examples/private_utxo/overview.html

Answer (score 2):

The Private UTXO link above is obsolete and pre-release.

There is an experimental feature called Sawtooth Private Data Objects (PDO). See
https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/private-data-objects/tree/master/sawtooth
For docs, see links in this tweet:
https://twitter.com/kellymolson/status/1019299515646406656

Alternatively, you can encrypt your payload so others without a private key cannot see it in the blockchain.  Or you can just store a hash/checksum in your payload.

Comment: I need to use PDO features, hope it's stable. Do I need to run the blockchain on SGX enabled processors (hardware)?

Comment: Yes, it requires SGX to keep the data private.

Answer (score 1):

We can use Private Transaction Families provided by the Hyperledger labs.

https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/private-transaction-families

> The system is based on a generic distributed ledger infrastructure (Hyperledger Sawtooth) and an Intel® SGX (Software Guard Extensions) 'hardened' Transaction Processor which provides a mechanism to enable Hyperledger Sawtooth to contain private information that is both not publicly available but required to validate transactions.

For more information about how Private Transaction Families work, see the following link

https://github.com/hyperledger-labs/private-transaction-families/blob/master/SPECIFICATION.md